# Terminate action in Bison

Tags: bison

What is the keyword to terminate an action in Bison but still continue the parsing?
Let's say I have this grammar:
Rule: something { if(something) terminate action; code} something {}...

It should just exit the current action and proceed, is it just return?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such keyword, so your best bet is to just invert the condition:

```
nonterm: pattern { if (!condition) {
                       /* Do what needs to be done */
                   }
                 }
```

Do **not** `return` from the semantic action. On some implementations, you might get away with `break` but I wouldn't try it. Even if it appears to work, it is not portable and could fail in the future or on a different platform.

If the rule has a semantic value, make sure you have set `$$` to something, since it is likely to be used.